# Is top displaying wrong result after calling malloc_trim()?

Tags: c, memory

I `free` memory about `3G`and then use `malloc_trim(0)` to return heap memory to system and watching resident memory usage with `top`. But the resident memory doesn't decrease. These memory is `malloc()`ed every time for about `54K` which is less than `128K`. And it is `malloc()`ed with `brk()` system call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [its docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc_trim),

> The `malloc_trim()` function **attempts** to release free memory **at the top of the heap**

(emphasis added).

It cannot release memory that has allocated memory above it on the heap, and therefore it does not guarantee to return anything to the system.  I'm inclined to think that little, if any, of the memory you want to release is at the top of the heap, though it's also possible that the memory is not actually free.

Note also that `malloc_trim()` is a GNU extension.